# Parsing a date string from the year 1753 in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to create the following Date object:

```
new Date("1753-01-01T04:00:00+01:00")
```

The date object then contains "Mon Jan 01 1753 04:05:21 GMT+0105".

Why do Chrome and Firefox add five minutes to the timezone offset?

Comment: timezone? here I get: `Mon Jan 01 1753 03:49:56 GMT+0049 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)` edit: `here` would be Italy

Comment: @Tom Where do you live?

Comment: I just ran the same code on w3schools and got "Mon Jan 01 1753 02:58:45 GMT-0001"  just by copying your code exactly.  The browser is Google Chrome.

Comment: I live in Austria, so I should have the same local timezone as GrafiCode in Italy, but nevertheless he gets a different result.

Comment: I did not check for Austria specifically, but this is most probably the same issue as for the linked duplicates.

Comment: I have checked using moment.js as well and it gives me the same result as @GrafiCode

Comment: @str: Thanks, yes I assume it's the same problem.